# php deprecation magic_quotes error won't go away

Tags: php, apache2, debian, magic-quotes-gpc

I know there is another topic on this from a while back, but there was never really a solid answer in there.

I'm running Debian 6, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3.  When I look at my phpinfo() output on the server, it shows magic_gpc_quotes as set to off.  My error.log file is getting spammed with this error though every time someone visits a page.

I've searched every single .ini file and in every single one of them, magic_quotes_gpc is set to off.

I'm using mod_fastcgi and php protected with Suhosin.  I'm not sure if either of those are affecting how magic_quotes_gpc acts, but I'm really at a loss for what to do.  Any help fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I have also run apt-get update and everything is up-to-date.

Running `grep -r 'magic_quotes_gpc' /` returns 3 php.ini files with all of them showing `magic_quotes_gpc = off`

I thought it might be mod_fastcgi causing the issue, so I disabled my scripts from using it and am still getting the error.

Comment: Magic quotes may be set with `ini_set`. `grep -R magic_gpc_quotes *`

Comment: Hrm, sorry, I'm new to this stuff (which is probably why I'm having the problem)... where and/or how do I look for that?

Comment: You should search for php files, where ini_set is called. I suggested how to use grep for that.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.  I ran `grep -R magic_gpc_quotes *` and didn't see any output so I tried `grep -R magic_gpc_quotes * > tmp.log` which resulted in an empty file.  Guess that means nothing found?

Comment: Yes. You should search from the root dir of your server, though.

Comment: Sorry... When I do that I get `grep: dev/log: No such device or address` as the only output

Answer (score 0):

Check if soMe PHP file uses `set_magic_quotes_runtime()`.